# Centering a pre-loader inside an image

Tags: html, css

I have a pre-loader, which is already centred inside an image. The pre-loader shows and then disappears when the image is loaded.

The thing I'm concerned about is that the pre-loader is only centred once the image loads. So before the image loads, the pre-loader is at the top of the div, then when the image loads, the pre-loader jumps down and then disappears.

This is ok as it still gives the user feedback but it's more of an aesthetic thing...and it's something I'm wondering about myself.

I understand the logic...the image isn't loaded, therefore the div that contains the image and spinner isn't stretched to accommodate the image and therefore the pre-loader isn't going to be at the 'right' place.

When I see a pre-loader, it normally sits in the centre of a container already for the image, then the image loads. So it's as if there is a container set up already that acts as if the image is loaded.

Here is my code for example:

HTML:

```
<a class="work_item_link" href="#">                            
        <div class="spinner">LOAD</div>
        <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1856788/thumbs/o-IMAGE-PHOTOSHOP-570.jpg?1">                           
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.spinner {
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.work_item_link {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    //margin-bottom: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8rjs25j/

Any input would be appreciated here.